# improving performance in sqoop apart from basic settings

Tags: sqoop

I want to improve performance in sqoop import. I am using sqoop version 1.4.7 and source db is oracle. I have one fact tbale which is having almost more than 100 million rows. I want to load this data into hadoop.
There are couple things where we can do like below

increase mappers by using --m option.
using boundary query
fetch size
I can't use direct query.(since this works on MYSQL and postgres)

Apart from these is there any oyher way to improve the performance.

Thanks in advance
Kumar

Comment: Hi, Any suggestions on above query

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could refer below site for the Performance tuning in sqoop

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/SQOOP-Performance-tuning/ta-p/248260

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks for sharing the valuable information. Those techniques already mentioned in my list. I would like to know are there still any other techniques available to import.